# IntelliJ Code Completion

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, intellisense, code-completion

I really like the Code Completion in Visual Studio: I have a Variable called `myrandomvariable`and when I type `myrand`followed by a dot or a space, VS automatically inserts `myrandomvariable`for me. I am so used to this, that in any other IDE I always expect the same behaviour and do not press ctrl+dot, enter or whatevers key combination. As I am using Android Studio I want to know if there exists a way to use the Visual Studio Style Code Completion in a IntelliJ IDE.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily enable this feature in IntelliJ.

Go to *Settings/Editor/Autocompletion* and check **insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.**

Btw: settings section was restructured a bit so this setting might be in a different location in IntelliJ 14 (I currently have 13 installed). But you should be able to find it easily using search dialog in case this is no longer the correct location for IntelliJ 14.

Comment: @ProgrammingMachine5000 Glad it worked for you :) Btw, if this solved your problem could you mark the answer as accepted (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about this...just did it, thanks for reminding.